# python script with zabbix causing setroubleshootd high CPU usage

Tags: python-requests, zabbix

I'm leveraging Zabbix with a custom low-level-discovery that discovers a REST/API endpoint using Python. When the polling is on, the CPU utilization goes through the roof. All the CPU usage is caused by setroubleshootd as show in top:

```
top - 13:51:56 up 15:33,  1 user,  load average: 1.52, 1.43, 1.37
Tasks: 127 total,   3 running, 124 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 35.8 us,  6.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 57.3 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8010508 total,  6211020 free,   397104 used,  1402384 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1679356 total,  1679356 free,        0 used.  6852016 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 7986 setroub+  20   0  424072 130856  11548 R  77.4  1.6   7:12.16
```

Zabbix calls the agent and requests to execute a "UserParameter" which is shorthand for a script. That script is a bash file that calls my python script. and the call looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/usr/bin/python /etc/zabbix/externalscripts/discovery.py $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
```

When zabbix calls the script, it passes the unique filters, like a server ID or network card ID, as one of the arguments. The python script opens up an https session using requests, leveraging a bearer token if the token file exists. If the token file doesn't exist it creates it.

The script works fine and does everything it is supposed to but setroubleshoot is rebooting a slew of issues, specifically around file folder access. The huge number of setroubleshootd responses is causing the CPU to go nuts. Here is an example of the error:

```
python: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from create access on the file 7WMXFl.
```

The file name is random and changes with every execution. I've tried adding an exception using the selinux tools such as:

```
 ausearch -c 'python' --raw | audit2allow -M my-python
```

But since the file name is random, the errors persist. I've tried uninstalling setroubleshootd, selinux just reinstalls it. Unfortunately, I need to run enforcing mode, so dropping to permissive or disabling are not options.

I've tried changing so that I'm not running a bash script, that zabbix calls the python script directly, or declaring shebang /usr/bin/python, but passing arguments doesn't seem to work properly. I get an error stating the $1 $2... are unknown arguments.

At a loss at this point. It is running, but I'd really like to get the CPU usage down as 60% of 4 cores is unreasonable for 30-40 HTTPS calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing an SEModule for this that allows the zabbix user write access to the /tmp folder where these files are being created and managed. CPU usage dropped from 75% to 2%. #NailedIt

```
$>sudo ausearch -m avc | grep zabbix | grep denied | audit2allow -m zabbixallow > my_script.te
$>checkmodule -M -m -o zabbixallow.mod my_script.te
$>semodule_package -o zabbixallow.pp -m zabbixallow.mod
$>sudo semodule -i zabbixallow.pp
```

Hopefully this helps someone else if they run across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

External scripts will have to complete within your timeout value, this sounds like it's too big for that.  You could convert it to zabbix_sender and schedule it via cron.  Then it's just a script with performance problems.

Comment: Is that what's causing the CPU usage to go high? The script runs pretty fast, the slowest requests return within about 350ms. Where is the timeout value? Can it be changed? The polling is happening once every 5m.

Comment: Also, the CPU usage is from setroubleshoot, not the script. There are no setroubleshoot alerts if I run it as a user, only if it is being run by the zabbix poller.